# What license does Stack Exchange use (GPL, MIT,...)

Tags: discussion, licensing, stack-overflow

What license does the Stack Exchange network (or Stack Overflow) use. Is it GPL, MIT, BSD, or any other free license? If it is so, how is the source code available?

Comment: Why do you assume it's free/open-source??

Comment: The fact that I say it this way does not mean am assuming it is open. The -1 for asking a simple question about the license is uncalled for. A simple answer like the one below is the correct to approach this instead of a negative way.

Comment: just to be clear - I didn't downvote you. I was just wondering what (the look? the kind of site?) made you think it would have to be free (since you only ever mentioned free/open-source licenses)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The source is not licensed.

https://stackexchange.com/legal

Comment: +1 For a helpful answer and giving the correct direction to learn more about this. Thank you Jason.